# Restricting access to Keycloak console from the internet on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-networkpolicy

Context: I am working in an application deployed in a CaaS and it has 2 ingresses for keycloak, each with a specific hostname, one of them is reachable from the internet.

What I want is NOT be able to access the Keycloak admin console from the internet.

I am trying this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource but can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if anyone else has this problem, but what I did was to change the ingress facing the internet so the path matches the prefix of the application realm instead of the master one and that is enough for us.

Comment: this works well, but I just gave few more options so that if people face relevant problems.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by changing rules in the external firewall (if it is available) and by using kubernetes native options like namespace isolation, network isolation and api isolation. In your case both network isolation and namespace isolation would also work. Follow this [document](https://www.synacktiv.com/en/publications/kubernetes-namespaces-isolation-what-it-is-what-it-isnt-life-universe-and-everything.html) for more information.

Comment: Yeah but in this case I think you would not be able to access the log in feature, right?

Comment: @Stieg still you will get the login feature but you might need a VPN to access this

Comment: @Stieg If you have deployed it onprem and are trying to access it from your home network you might need a VPN because that onprem private network will be accessible in your DC or in your office network.